# reference for the weak compactness of currents

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-ricci-flow

I am trying to follow the arguments in page 22 of the following paper [k\"{a}hler currents and null loci](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5216.pdf)

It quotes the weak compactness of currents, I wonder if there is any reference about it. My knowledge about currents are all from [Demailly's notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf)

Basically, you can define a norm on the space of $p$ forms, and it will be a Frechet space, then you can talk about weak topology. Does weak compactness mean that the space of currents are weakly compact? If that is true, we also need a way to identify the space of $p$ forms as a subspace of the currents. I guess it can be done through the metric. Is there any reference that actually goes through all these constructions in detail?

Comment: The inclusion of smooth forms into currents is standard (example 2.5 chapter I page 15 of Demailly's book). The weak compactness statement is Proposition 1.23 in chapter III of Demailly's book (page 136). To apply it, take the function $\delta$ there to be a small positive constant, and note that the Kahler metrics $\omega(t)$ to which the proposition is applied live in a family of cohomology classes which lie inside a bounded set in cohomology, hence the integrals $\int_X \omega(t)\wedge\omega^{n-1}$ are bounded above by a fixed constant $C$ independent of $t$. Then take $\delta=1/C$.

Comment: Thank you very much!